# How do you describe something being encircled by a collection of things which get progressively concentrated towards the centre?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a particular word which accurately describes a collection of things that encircle another thing uniformly, with their concentration and population growing towards the centre. A few examples I can think of;

- The way that populations grow in numbers the closer you get to a city's centre.
- The way crowds might gather around a preacher
- How iron filings are attracted to a magnet
- (the reverse) How sound waves are emitted from the centre of a speaker.

**EDIT**

An example sentence might look like; *The man drew a crowd until he was entirely ***something***ed by eager listeners who looked up with intrigue and adoration.*

Comment: For [[single word requests]] please include a sample sentence showing how the word will be used.  Any words that did not fit the bill also help with your research.

Comment: I believe that there is a name for this kind of distribution in mathematics, so if you have no luck here (after including a sample sentence, of course, as @livresque suggests), then you may be able to get an answer on one of SE's math sites.

Comment: I'm thinking of the situation you see in a cowboy movie where a group like in a wagon train is being circled by bandits or some such.  There's a term for this but I can't remember it.

Comment: What's the matter with _surrounded_?

Comment: A *swarm* is concentrated in the center.

Comment: @JohnLawler surrounded doesn't convey dissipation from the centre.

Answer (score 1):

One word that might describe the phenomenon you are describing is "concentric.". Concentric means having a common center or axis, so a collection of things that encircle another thing uniformly with their concentration growing towards the center could be said to be concentric. This word is often used to describe circles or other shapes that share a common center, but it could also be used to describe the type of population growth or gathering of people you are describing.

Comment: Thank you @Nova that's a good suggestion. As you say, it's a helpful term to express rings that have some element of concentration around a common centre. I think the key difference is that concentric circles are discrete, each representing a value - and in this case I'm looking for something that represents a continuous scale of concentration. Thank you again for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a single verb that accurately convey's the OP's description, but using the same verb in the example sentence, we can say “to draw someone/something near, closer” which suggest people from different points, meeting together at the centre.

Enraptured, the crowd **[drew closer](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20crowd%20drew%20closer%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsZFhtkUkCSCXq-MjRGDOcKQ5oGlaA:1670157220587&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAo-i-_N_7AhXzX_EDHXG1DfkQ_AUoAXoECAIQCw&biw=1152&bih=637&dpr=2.5)**, as they listened to him speak.